# I thought I’ve sounded good while singing along to my music, but when I recorded my self after 1 year of practicing, I think I sound horrible

Tags: voice, production

So, for the past year and a half I’ve been practicing my singing by simply listening to my music and singing it out loud in a shed in the back of my house. In December, I got a little studio to record my own music and started using the studio microphone and headphones to listen to my music and sing along whilst hearing my own voice behind the track. Today, I thought I’ve finally done it and recorded myself on my phone. It surprised me how bad I still sounded even after almost two years of me practicing myself. I want to become an artist and make my own music but after today my ego has taken a massive hit and I no longer think I’m going to make music any more. I May use vocal presets so it will make my bad singing sound better but, how can I make my singing sound more natural, less strained, less nasally, less “moany” and more full?

Comment: How old are you? Less than 20? In your 30s? ...50 or older? Teenagers are still developing, and my vocal range even dropped well into my 20s, but my family says that I'll only go downhill (and never uphill) body-wise after I turn(ed) 30.

Comment: I am 15, 16 in November.

Comment: So, if you were to hear my voice, I’m my natural talking voice, you’ll hear that I’m probably going to stick with that voice forever. It’s like in a tenor registry and I know technique and how to pull off stuff singers do, but I just sound bad. I want to make my own music like, now, but I think I’ll have to put it off until I’m 18-20.

Comment: Hi Jared - I have closed as a duplicate of a previous question as it will give you the general things you can do. For yourself, a vocal coach is essential if you wish to fully unlock your potential - and that cannot be done on a Q&A site. Good luck

Comment: One extra thing that wasn't mentioned on the duplicate: When you record yourself, you're adding a lot to the experience—the mic you choose, where you place it, the medium you record onto, the speakers you play it back on. You're asking yourself not just to learn singing but audio engineering. I strongly advise: just get a teacher! They're used to knowing what they hear, *and* can help you improve!

Comment: Even the pros sometimes cringe when they hear recordings of themselves.  I remember once, in music school, playing a first rehearsal accompanying a student singer.  I thought the student was phenomenal, but she was incredibly disappointed in herself and when she left, she thanked us and said she was going home to practice. / Find a teacher you trust and see where it leads you.  At your age, it is too soon to know where your voice will be in a few years.  You will learn so much about diction, breath control, etc.  Also, join a good choral group if you can.

Comment: Take singing lessons. And use a proper microphone, your phone is (usually) useless for recording live music.